# R: Assign vector element as list variable name

Tags: r, list

Here is the end result that I would like to achieve:

```
json_creative_pause = list("47770124" = 
         list(patch = list(
             `$set` = list (
                 status = "PAUSED"
             ))))
```

The issue is that I would like to create this same structure dynamically for multiple ids. I have this variable:

```
creative_ids_to_pause = c("75196186", "78369656", "80050466")
```

And I would like to recreate the same structure for each creative id. But running such code doesn't really work:

```
json_creative_pause = list(get(creative_ids_to_pause[1]) = 
                                   list(patch = list(
                                       `$set` = list (
                                           status = "PAUSED"
                                       ))))
```

Does anyone know how to assign a vector element as a variable name inside of a list?

Thank you for your help!

Arben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
setNames(list(patch = list(
                                   `$set` = list (
                                       status = "PAUSED"
                                   ))), creative_ids_to_pause[1])

#$`75196186`
#$`75196186`$`$set`
#$`75196186`$`$set`$status
#[1] "PAUSED"
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr::lst`

```
dplyr::lst(!! creative_ids_to_pause[1] := 
                                    list(patch = list(
                                        `$set` = list (
                                            status = "PAUSED"
                                        ))))
#$`75196186`
#$`75196186`$patch
#$`75196186`$patch$`$set`
#$`75196186`$patch$`$set`$status
#[1] "PAUSED"
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this solution:

```
creative_ids_to_pause = c("75196186", "78369656", "80050466")

unnamed_json_structure = list(
    patch = list(
        `$set` = list(
            status = "PAUSED"
        )))

list_all_creative_ids = list()

for(i in 1:length(creative_ids_to_pause)){
    
    list_all_creative_ids[[creative_ids_to_pause[i]]] = unnamed_json_structure
    
}

list_all_creative_ids %>% 
    toJSON(pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Result

```
  "75196186": {
    "patch": {
      "$set": {
        "status": "PAUSED"
      }
    }
  },
  "78369656": {
    "patch": {
      "$set": {
        "status": "PAUSED"
      }
    }
  },
  "80050466": {
    "patch": {
      "$set": {
        "status": "PAUSED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```